# Redirecting folder to root with rewrite and masked

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect and mask directory `domain.com/presta/index.php` to be `domain.com/index.php`, can be possible?

I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(?!presta/)(.*)$ /presta/$1
```

But redirect me from `domain.com/` to `domain.com/presta`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^presta/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,R,L]
```